# NTFS partition works slow after booting from windows to ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs, disk

I have dual booted ubuntu and windows (different partitions ofcourse) on my machine.

After working on windows for a while, and then rebooting to ubuntu, one of my NTFS partitions works extremely slow.

```
/dev/sda4       100G   97G  3.7G  97% /mnt/c
/dev/sda8       319G  302G  396M 100% /mnt/g
/dev/sda6       200G  194G  6.4G  97% /mnt/e
/dev/sda7       200G  145G   56G  73% /mnt/f
```

sda8 is exfat. The rest of the partitions are NTFS. I'm having issues with sda7.

My windows partition (sda4) and one another NTFS partition (sda6) work totally fine.
But on this specific partition (sda7), I get write speed around 127 KB/s and after a while, it increased to 300 KB/s

After a lot of time, it automatically goes to the normal speed.

Can someone tell me what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, not mounting at all, or operating slowly, it's probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: